# How to implement an alternative rotation in a factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I have an application of factor analysis, where the theoretical model specifies that certain loadings *within each factor* should ideally share a same sign for the sake of interpretability.  For example, if I have 7 variables from which I am keeping 2 factors, ideally loadings for v4, v5, v6, and v7 in factor 1 should have the same sign, and v4, v5, v6, and v7 in factor 2 should have the same sign (but not necessarily the same sign as factor 1--obviously, you can multiply any component by -1 if you really want them all to have the same sign without changing the subspace)

Intuitively, this seems like something I could do with a varimax-like procedure, except maximizing the magnitude of the means of the loadings instead of the variances.  Also, ideally whatever method I use should only target the relevant loadings and not concern the other ones (i.e. v1, v2, and v3 have no restrictions in my example), although throwing varimax at the remaining loadings to enure a repeatable set of factors for each data set I need to analyze doesn't seem unreasonable.

I can't find any source that gives the nuts-and-bolts for how the optimization algorithm performed in varimax is actually implemented.  Could it be adjusted to work in my application?  What if I modify the problem such that the resulting post-rotation components don't have to be orthonormal (i.e., use an oblique rotation)?  Does a tool that does what I need already exist somewhere?